# AWS Lambda function use payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, python-3.9

I have a python lambda function that i use to get a status report on an AMI export, I need to send a variable as a payload using an AWS cli command but for some reasons I cannot get the function to use the data in the payload.

This is my function :

```
import json
import boto3
import os

AMI_PROCESS_ID = os.environ['AMI_PROCESS_ID']
client = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.describe_export_image_tasks(
        DryRun=False,
        ExportImageTaskIds=[
            AMI_PROCESS_ID
        ],
        MaxResults=123,
        NextToken='teststeatasrfdasdas'
    )
    return response
```

If I set the environmental variable AMI_PROCESS_ID in the function it works without any issue

This is the aws cli command I'm sending

```
 aws lambda invoke --function-name test_deleteme --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{"AMI_PROCESS_ID": "export-ami-12354564534d"}' response.json --profile my-profile  --no-verify-ssl
```

This is the content of the response.json

```
{"errorMessage": "'AMI_PROCESS_ID'", "errorType": "KeyError", "requestId": "", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n", "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n", "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n", "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n", "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n", "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n", "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n", "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 5, in <module>\n    AMI_PROCESS_ID = os.environ['AMI_PROCESS_ID']\n", "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 679, in __getitem__\n    raise KeyError(key) from None\n"]}
```

This is pretty much telling me that the content of the variable AMI_PROCESS_ID is empty

I cannot find documentation on how to unpack a payload, It seems that the os.environ is the way to go but it is not processing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) is the documentation, and here is how you extract the `AMI_PROCESS_ID` from the payload:

```
import json
import boto3
import os


client = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    AMI_PROCESS_ID = event['AMI_PROCESS_ID']
    response = client.describe_export_image_tasks(
        DryRun=False,
        ExportImageTaskIds=[
            AMI_PROCESS_ID
        ],
        MaxResults=123,
        NextToken='teststeatasrfdasdas'
    )
    return response
```